# C - how to compare index on 2 string?

Tags: c, string, algorithm

i have 2 string;

`string1[20] = "ab cd efgf";
string2[20] = "mn go jpfgt";`

Need to find the first letter in string1 that appears in string 2
and after print the place(index) and the letter In each of the strings
need to find only letter not numbers or space

for example: the letter f, in place 8 in string 1, in place 9 in string 2

Comment: Any attempt at solving this independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We beginners should help each other.:)
Here is my three cents.:)

For starters indices in C start from zero.

So it would be correctly to say that

> the letter f, in place 7 in string 1, in place 8 in string 2

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int find_letter( const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t *i1, size_t *i2 )
{
    int success = *s1 && *s2;

    if ( success )
    {
        const char *p1 = s1;
        const char *p2;

        do
        {
            success = isalpha( ( unsigned char )*p1 ) && 
                      ( p2 = strchr( s2, *p1 ) ) != NULL;  
        } while ( !success && *++p1 );

        if ( success )
        {
            *i1 = p1 - s1;
            *i2 = p2 - s2;
        }
    }

    return success;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char string1[] = "ab cd efgf";
    char string2[] = "mn go jpfgt";
    size_t i1;
    size_t i2;

    if ( find_letter( string1, string2, &i1, &i2 ) )
    {
        printf( "%c at position %zu in the first string "
                "and at position %zu in the second string\n",
                string1[i1], i1, i2 );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
f at position 7 in the first string and at position 8 in the second string
```

Comment: in find(), what happens if s1 or s2 are NULL? Apart from this, congratulations for the effort.

Comment: @linuxfan Undefined behavior. As with standard C string functions it is the task of the client of the function to pass valid pointers.